# Replace substring with another string rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, replace

In my rails app, I am saving a question as html. For example,

```
"<p>&lt;pre dir=\"ltr\" style=\"background-color: #ede7db; color:
#000000; margin: 0px; padding: 6px; border: 1px inset; width: 640px; height: 194px; text-align: left; overflow: auto; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;\" class=\"alt2\"&gt;void myFunc (int x) <br />{ <br /> if (x &amp;gt; 0)<br /> myFunc(--x); <br /> printf(\"%d, \", x); <br />} <br />int main() <br />{ <br /> myFunc(5); <br /> return 0; <br />}&lt;/pre&gt;</p>"
```

I need to replace all the width attributes with `width:auto;`

Help me to do the same. Thanks :)-

Comment: You seem to have some serious issues with some escaping here (&lt; etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, assuming the string is in a variable `s`:

```
s.gsub(/width:[^;]*;/, 'width: auto;')
```

Comment: I think you need to add the global flag in your regex so that it replaces 'all' width attributes.

Comment: gsub does this by default: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub

Comment: Ahh, you're right. I didn't notice you used gsub instead of sub. :)

Comment: @Chirag64, Ruby doesn't have a "global flag" for regex patterns. Perhaps you're confusing Ruby and Perl or another language. `gsub` is the implementation of "global flag", done in a method that does search/replace globally in the String, whereas `sub` only does the first matching pattern.